# Best Way to FFT - Max. Value FFT - Python

Tags: python, floating-point, fft, raspberry-pi3, decibel

I am trying to build an SPL measurement device with the raspberry written in Python.
I record a sound and then I do the FFT but I don't have right value in logarithm.

```
    fs_rate, signal = wavfile.read(filename)
    l_audio = len(signal.shape)
    if l_audio == 2:
        signal = signal.sum(axis=1) / 2
    N = signal.shape[0]
    secs = (N / float(fs_rate))
    Ts = 1.0/fs_rate # sampling interval in time
    t = scipy.arange(0, secs, Ts) # time vector as scipy arange field / numpy.ndarray
    FFT = abs(scipy.fft(signal))
    FFT_side = FFT[range(N//2)] # one side FFT range
    freqs = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(signal.size, t[1]-t[0])
    fft_freqs = np.array(freqs)
    freqs_side = freqs[range(N//2)] # one side frequency range
    fft_freqs_side = np.array(freqs_side)
    fft_log = 94 + np.log10((FFT_side/(1.79*10**308)))       
    print("Type: %s" % (FFT_side.dtype))
```

Above you can see the FFT code I am using. 
I have 2 questions:

1. FFT_side is a float64 value, what is the max range?

My processor is the armv7l 32bit. I've found on the internet that this is the max range 1.7976931348623157e+308, is that correct?

2. How can I get a dB graph without knowing what is the voltage across the microphone? 
   I thought to do value_read/max_float64 but this is not working at all.

Comment: To measure SPL you need a calibrated reference signal. dB values are arbitrary *ratios* relative to some reference value (e.g. full scale input, or some other nominal reference). [`dB SPL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level) is a ratio relative to a reference SPL (20 µPa), which is why you need a calibrated reference. (Bonus points: if you want to do it properly you also need to calibrate across a range of frequencies, since your microphone frequency response will not be flat.)

Comment: I've understood the theory but I didn't understand how I can calibrate a reference signal. What would I do is build a 1kHz sine at max value and relate it to the measured one. For example: fft_log = 94  + 20*log(mesured_singal / ref_signal ). Is that correct?

Comment: For accurate calibration you would usually use a calibrated sound source - this is a hardware device which generates an audio tone at a specific frequency and SPL. Alternatively you could borrow or hire an SPL meter and calibrate your app against that.